# Select multiple transformed columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
name
-----------
45Paris123
23HaNoi456
35Qatar789
```

Here is the function

```
name1 = mid(name, 3, 8)
name2 = left(name1, 5)
name3 = left(name2, 2)
```

So that the final result is

```
name3
------
Pa
Ha
Qa
```

Both table and function are simplified. It can be much more complicated so the combination of function is not really viable

How can we make it?

Comment: With out showing what is the complexity you have to deal with how can we find something?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @ducvu169! How do you tell which row is name1, name2, etc.? Is there an ID column?

Comment: @ollie,you can understand what op is asking if RDBMS attached?

Comment: Just being transferred from using Excel to Sql. I mainly use T- SQL

Comment: If sometimes it's `123Paris123` instead of `12Paris123`. Using the index will be use less. So we need at least to know what is the complexity and what is constant. Or if `123` could also be some letter or random punctuation

Comment: name1, name2, name3 are just 3 columns. name1 get and transform data from column name, nam2 from name1 and name3 from name2.None of them are ID columns

Comment: I would have format my csv to make it Worth going to DB. With some C# regex and string split, string join.

Comment: Pierre Lebon : I knew this and I actually can transform data in Python with string function and regex. Is that in SQL, it is not viable to make a sequence of columns that 1 column is based on previous one? let' s say column4 from 3, 3 from 2, 2 from 1

Comment: I thing I understand your question, but can you add all your comment statement to your post via [edit] so it's more clear for everyone?

Comment: Your question is so incredibly vague it is a wonder anybody has actually posted an attempt at an answer. You talk about columns but you showed them as rows. In its current state, this question is a hot mess with nowhere near enough details. Try reading this and follow the advice here for improving this question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange, I'm like a ruber duck. Op say Something even him don't understand. I answer with what I understood. And some times it help Op understanding his own question. The question is so unclear it will be close soon. I have try my best to make a clear statement based on my poor understanding. But as Op is still here and doesn't run away as soon as he posted, I will wait for his edit.

Comment: @PierreLebon I applaud your efforts. I just have no idea what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange, I think some "complexe transformation" on a badly stored data, so he try to simplify with "helper variable" and use alias for that. This is what come to my mind on the first read. I just hope we didn't scared him with our talk. but i'm pretty sure this will end with an `over (partition ...` or Something like that when Op will give us a real data to work on.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you want to use a column as base for an other column.

It's possible only if the column exist in the table. If you are talking about alias of a computed column , the answer is no.

Because alias are not part of the `select critera`, you can only select `*` or `column name` or `expression`

```
<select_criteria> ::=  
    [ TOP ( top_expression ) ]   
    [ ALL | DISTINCT ]   
    { * | column_name | expression }
```

But you can recompute it like :

```
SELECT  name AS input
        , mid(name,3,8) AS name1
        , left(mid(name,3,8),5) AS name2
        , left(left(mid(name,3,8),5),2) AS name3
FROM    myTable
```

Or Use [SELECT ... INTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql)

```
select *
into #TempTable
from YourTable

select *
from #TempTable
```

The best solution will be to work on this before it get to DB.
A simple regex like this : `\d+|\D+`, should do the trick. Explanation and test [here](https://regex101.com/r/6MgzFg/1/).

Comment: Thanks alot but sadly, I already knew that answer. So SQL is only used for some simple data transformation, not for deeper analysis with a lot of calculation and data turnaround   . So if I want to do some code for deeper analysis, things like VBA/Python is better, right?

Comment: Sql can be use for anything! As long as what you want is clear. you can find on Google many blog on data mining with sql request. Doing matrix  from pure data.

Comment: I just think your question is unclear because you are trying to simplify the data. Sql should be use to get the data, if they are store correctly (not the case here if you have to do all those substring). And Other language should be use for calculation and display. the choice between X or Y language is based on your knowledge.

Comment: @ducvu169, i have add temp table that could be a part of the solution.